# APP Insights Pattern Machine Learning

Tags: c#, excel, machine-learning, neural-network

I have recently started learning Neural networks and have been watching and reading neural networks for the past one month. So now i am trying to actually implement something. We have app insights logging in our WEB API which will log all the exceptions and request , i have excel for such datas for the past one year. Is it possible to predict what all exceptions might happen tomorrow based the data set i have in hand.

Please reply and let me know your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: "Is it possible to predict what all exceptions might happen tomorrow based the data set i have in hand.": No, it is not. At least not exactly and in general. Predictions always are problematic, especially concerning the future.

Comment: did my answer help you

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yeah, it guided me in the right path. I have one more question has well, Do you have any app insights analytics query to track down the root cause of an exception?

Comment: Yeah will share it, please mark if the answer helped

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of crazy question, Now my view on this would be,

(i) App Insights stores data only for 90 days, and the purpose of app insights is using to find production/development bugs and resolve them immediately. If you have a bug you need to resolve them immediately.

(ii)Machine learning is something totally different, this can be applied for a historical data, the same errors/exceptions are going to happen in your web app until you resolve them, i do not see any point in predicting what exceptions might occur later which is purely depend on the code you've written.

There are certain things you could do with this, you can do some analysis with **[`Jupyter notebook`](https://notebooks.azure.com/)** by calling the app Insights api.